# Is there a way to detect when a participant has muted their audio in opentok.js?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I went through the publisher docs which has the methods `publishVideo(value)` and `publishAudio(value)`.
Corresponding to the video part, the subscriber receives the event `videoDisabled` or `videoEnabled` with the reason `publishVideo` which allows me to determine whether the subscribed participant has intentionally turned off their video or not, but I can't find something similar for audio such as `audioDisabled` or `audioEnabled`. `audioBlocked` event supposedly only covers blocks by browser's autoplay policy: `Dispatched when the subscriber's audio is blocked because of the browser's autoplay policy`.

The `audioLevelUpdated` event provides the current audio level, but that could just be silence, not an intentional mute, so that doesn't look ideal for this purpose.

I want to show a audio muted icon on the subscribed participants element when they have intentionally turned off their audio by calling `publishAudio()` method. How can that be achieved?

Referenced docs:

Subscriber events: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#events

Publisher methods: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each stream has an `hasAudio` attribute that returns false if the user's audio is muted or their microphone is muted. Similarly, streams also have a `hasVideo` attribute. You can reference the stream docs at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Stream.html.

I personally use it like so:

```
session.streams.forEach((stream) => {
    const name = stream.name;
    const video = stream.hasVideo;
    const audio = stream.hasAudio;
});
```

You can listen for these changes with the `session.on('streamPropertyChanged')` event: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamPropertyChangedEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

Hav u tried audioLevelUpdated and checking the level of audio

If level is 0 then its muted.

https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getAudioVolume

So steps are listen audioLevelUpdated and check AudioVolume, audio volume should get u the subscriber level point.

Comment: Thanks Gopal, but as I mentioned in the question the value returned by audioLevelUpdated being 0 can potentially indicate silence as well, right? Or is there something I'm missing?

Are you implying that the probability of that happening is so low that I can safely use it as an indicator for mute?

Comment: I wil update u, becasue in my last project we used it to track the vol level and it worked.

Comment: The audioLevel can definitely be 0 with the microphone not muted. In fact, in my project, upon stream init, the audioLevelUpdated event is always thrown with an audioLevel of 0 before it throws a different number.

Comment: I've made it so on audioLevelUpdated event thrown, I check both subscriber.stream.hasAudio and event.audioLevel. Seems to remove the case where mic is unmuted, but no sound is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Set OTSubscriberKitNetworkStatsDelegate to subscriber as

```
subscriber.networkStatsDelegate = self
```

Then you can call the below function to get simultaneous changes on subscribers' microphone status

```
func subscriber(_ subscriber: OTSubscriberKit, audioNetworkStatsUpdated stats: OTSubscriberKitAudioNetworkStats) {
         // call stream.hasAudio 
     }
```

You can also check from [opentok audioNetworkStatsUpdated](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSubscriberKitNetworkStatsDelegate.html)